# how to get similar values from two data frame. based on id that is not unique

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

[image]

i have another data frame that also have similar `id` and data i want to get all data from first data frame and all from second of that id and check both similar value is any value is missing in any `DataFrame` then tag `NA`

While i am applying `merge()` it generates duplicate records but i want all record of 817 id's from 1st data frame and all record from 2nd

[image]

Comment: post your data as code please. Include a minimum reproducible example, the current output and the desired output.